# Arara synctex in editing a book

Tags: books, forward-inverse-search, arara, pdfsync

The problem is synctex in Arara does not work for me.

I am using MacTeX with TeXShop 4.26. A special documentclass is used (hope it does not affect). For months, I run this file by putting all the supporting files like chp1.tex into the same file folder and clicking command+T. Synchronising from pdf to tex and everything else is fine except synchronising from tex to pdf. Synchronising from tex to pdf works well in editing any other simple file using pdflatex directly (rather than using Arara). Is there anything wrong?

```
% !TEX TS-program = Arara
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: bibtex
% arara: makeindex
% arara: nomencl
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: yes}
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: on}
\documentclass[cmyk]{***}
\usepackage{amsrefs}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx,tikz,amscd}
\usepackage[hyperindex,colorlinks,pageanchor]{hyperref}
\usepackage[capitalize]{cleveref}
\makeindex
\usepackage[refpage]{nomencl}
\makenomenclature
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\input{front}
\tableofcontents
\include{preface}
\mainmatter
\include{chp1}
\include{chp2}
\appendix
\include{appd}
\backmatter
\bibliographystyle{amsalpha}
\bibliography{biblio}
\printindex
\printnomenclature
\pagestyle{empty}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, I will take a look soon. `:)`

Comment: ooh The duck has it under control :-) however it may be a red herring, that I note that most arara instructions tend to have a space before and after { and before } but as I don't have it installed can't test if that makes any difference

Comment: @KJO Thanks for the reminding. I tested it and the brace-spaces do not affect.

Comment: The syntax is correct, otherwise `arara` would complain about it. `:)` When running the tool with the `--dry-run` option, I see that the commands are correct. Are you sure the tool does not fail in any step before the two last directives? My suspicion is that the last two directives are not being reached due to a failed execution in previous directives (as `arara` halts the execution). We might need to inspect the log. Could you run `arara` with `--log` enabled and post the contents of `arara.log`?

Comment: Not trying to use the typical "not my fault" excuse, but `arara` is just a wrapper to the actual TeX programs. That's why I suspect there's a break in the compilation chain and the lines with SyncTeX are not reached. `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda Thanks Paulo! I am not sure the tool succeeds in any step. But removing the parts
    : { synctex: yes }
and
    : { synctex: on }
yields a pdf which supports neither of the two directions of synchronizations. So I supposed that the last two directives were reached. I ran ``arara --log main.tex'' in terminal and here is the arara.log file: https://www.filehosting.org/file/details/786471/arara.log

Comment: Without knowing the class, how can we test? And no, I'm not going to hand out my email address to the filehosting site

Comment: @egreg Thanks for the reply! The file arara.log asked by Paulo is 117 kb which is too large to be allowed posted here. Is there some better way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

<sup>I deliberately marked this answer as community wiki because it is not actually a direct answer, but along the lines of an elaborate comment which is too long to be posted as such. I really don't feel like harvesting reputation. `:)`</sup>

For starters, thanks for the log. `:)`

It is clear, from inspecting the log, that `arara` successfully goes through all the motions of executing the commands mapped from the directives. However, to me, there's no clear indication that the tool is to blame on the issue reported in this question. I will expand on that.

`arara` is just like a wrapper to ease the call for the actual programs like `pdflatex` and friends. In fact, if I take the provided code and run through the tool with `--dry-run` enabled, we can see what `arara` is actually executing on a normal scenario (in here, without an a call, surely, since this flag disables the actual execution):

```
$ arara --dry-run 478314.tex 
  __ _ _ __ __ _ _ __ __ _ 
 / _` | '__/ _` | '__/ _` |
| (_| | | | (_| | | | (_| |
 \__,_|_|  \__,_|_|  \__,_|

Processing '478314.tex' (size: 231 bytes, last modified:
03/10/2019 17:53:47), please wait.

[DR] (PDFLaTeX) PDFLaTeX engine
-----------------------------------------------------------------
Authors: Marco Daniel, Paulo Cereda
About to run: [ pdflatex, 478314.tex ]

[DR] (BibTeX) The BibTeX reference management software
-----------------------------------------------------------------
Authors: Marco Daniel, Paulo Cereda
About to run: [ bibtex, 478314 ]

[DR] (MakeIndex) The MakeIndex software
-----------------------------------------------------------------
Authors: Marco Daniel, Paulo Cereda
About to run: [ makeindex, -t, 478314.ilg, 478314.idx, -o,
478314.ind ]

[DR] (Nomencl) The Nomenclature software
-----------------------------------------------------------------
Authors: Marco Daniel, Nicola Talbot, Paulo Cereda
About to run: [ makeindex, 478314.nlo, -s, nomencl.ist, -o,
478314.nls ]

[DR] (PDFLaTeX) PDFLaTeX engine
-----------------------------------------------------------------
Authors: Marco Daniel, Paulo Cereda
About to run: [ pdflatex, --synctex=1, 478314.tex ]

[DR] (PDFLaTeX) PDFLaTeX engine
-----------------------------------------------------------------
Authors: Marco Daniel, Paulo Cereda
About to run: [ pdflatex, --synctex=1, 478314.tex ]

Total: 0.42 seconds
```

The last two calls to `pdflatex` have the `--synctex=1` flag, which is expected to provide proper SyncTeX support. That's it.

However, little to nothing can be done without delving into the depths of your actual environment and code in order to see what is happening. My suggestion is to independently run

```
pdflatex --synctex=1 myfile.tex
```

in the command line and see what happens. I can think of some scenarios:

1. The editor is not aware that there was a compilation chain that generated the resulting PDF, thus nothing is updated, or
2. You have directives in your source code (not shown in this particular example) that get rid of `synctex.gz` files as a means to declutter the directory, or
3. There are potential conflicts in the source code that are causing this issue.

Speaking of which, I noticed that the log file contains a lot of warning about cross references. Although SyncTeX is not directly related to it, maybe it's something worth checking. From my side, I tried a couple of documents of mine and they worked, so I really cannot reproduce this issue, I am so sorry.

Please try to run `pdflatex` as a standalone call instead of using `arara` and see if it works. Also, try other similar tools like `latexmk`. If the problem persists, we might need to get down to a minimal working example that reproduces the issue, otherwise I can only suppose.

Sorry for not being able to help you on this issue. Please keep me informed.

Comment: Thanks Paulo! An independent run of
    pdflatex --synctex=1 myfile.tex
produces a pdf with the same problem. You are right there is a lot of cross-refs. I  understand your 3 scenarios more or less, but am still quite confused about the direction that I should dig deeper. I'll try check the cross-refs so. Thanks for all and please let me know if the above result inspires anything new.

Comment: @DavidWang I am the one to thank you! `:)` I was getting worried that this could somehow be a corner case, a very specific scenario in which things were not behaving as expected. Thanks for testing. I think we can now cross items 1 and 2, since the issue is reproduceable without TeXShop and `arara`. Sadly, I won't be able to help you further, since SyncTeX is an uncharted territory to me. Perhaps changing this question a bit might help others investigate what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution: Add `% !TEX root = main.tex` at the beginning of the file for each chapter, such as that of the file chp1.tex. This command assigns a relative path so that the generated sync file finds the main file which contains a line of \include{chp1}. An alternative solution is to add an absolute path like
`% !TEX root = /Users/main.tex` if `/Users/main.tex` is the location of the file main.tex on my Mac. The problem should be about editing a book in multi-files, rather than using Arara.